# Mapping a Map collection of list<Entity> hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have two tables with one to many mapping. Orders:

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   |     id     |   Name      |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 |     1      |    Order    |
| 2 |     2      |    Order    |
| 3 |     3      |    Order    |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

and dishes:

```
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |     id     |   Name      |  Order_id   |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 |     1      |    Dish     |      1      |
| 2 |     2      |    Dish     |      1      |
| 3 |     3      |    Dish     |      1      |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

So in my order entity I managed to map a Map Collection with every dish id and its entity, but is there a way to map every order_id in a:

```
Map<Integer, List<Dish>>
```

Where Integer is order_id and in the list every dish mapped to it or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: So , some entity will have many orders. Do have have such entity in reality and what is it ?

Comment: @KenChan Dishes has many orders it's one to many. And if three dishes have the same order I want to be able to put that order id in a map key and all the different dishes in the value as list. So if I write map.getKey(*the id of the order*) to get all dishes mapped to it.

Comment: but from the table structure you showed , one order has  many dishes , but not one dish has many orders. So it is very confused actually........

Comment: @KenChan "And if three dishes have the same order..." I just made a mistake in the first sentence, but the rest of the comment explains it all. The first sentence should be "Order has many dishes it's one to many".

Comment: Then back to my original question , which entity will have many order ? `Map<Integer, List<Dish>> ` need to be inside this entity.

Comment: @KenChan Should the mapping be again one to many or is it possible to be one to one? I don't have that entity, but because I really will benefit from that functionality, there can be another one like Table. table will have an order and the order will have many dishes.

Answer (score 0):

Not understood what `entity` you're talking about but for the end result you can use Joins with following query:

```
Select distinct 
t1.id, t2.name
from Orders t1
join Dishes t2
on t1.id = t2.order_id
Order by t1.id
```

Now save this result in `ResultSet` data structure and put it inside `Map<>` by iterating the `resultset`.

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word, making it a poor choice as a table/column identifier.

Comment: Apparently , the OP want to know how to do that in Hibernate way , but not in native SQL.....